# I connected c# windows app with Access database (accdb) but the application doesn't work on other computers

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, database-connection

I connected an Access database (accdb) with C#-windows application project.
The "accdb" database is located in a folder in desktop. It works correctly on my computer but when i build a setup file and installed it on other computer the software didn't work. (i know the problem is that the database located in the folder) but i dont't know how to change the code that after installation on other computer, it can still connect to the database.
Does anyone know how should i solve this problem?
Here is the simple connection that i wrote:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\aa\Test.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;");
```

Comment: In other computers, do you have same access db? Same name? Same folder path?

Comment: Two options, either have a user point to the db and or it should sit along side of the app directory and change your connection string to reflect that, you cant hard code it like that.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Tnx. How can i change my connection string to (reflect that)?
can you please write it?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe: Tnx. No on the other computer i have none of them. I need to change this hard code but i don't know how :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works correctly on my computer but when i build a setup file and installed it on other computer the software didn't work.

The primary reason for this is because that path doesn't exist on the other machine; you've hard-coded your path.

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\aa\Test.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;");
```

`C:\Users\aa\Test.accdb` this is the actual issue, you shouldn't hard code this value, instead you have two options I can think of.

1. Look for the file along side the application where it is being executed from (this requires the file to be inside the same directory the exe is in).
2. You could allow the end user to enter the location of that file, if it exist, save this path to use again when needed.

You can use either or I mention above and or do both of them, your choice. Below is a simple example using option one above.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO; 

public static string GetDBConnection()
{
   try
   {
      string dbExecPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Test.accdb");
      return $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={ dbExecPath };Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123;";
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
      return string.Empty;
   }            
}
```

This get's the assemblies location (path) and combines it with your file name (db file). Then combine's that with your other connection string parts and return's the whole connection string.

**Please Note:** the namespaces that have to be used and the db file must be in the same directory that the exe is if going this route.

Now you can call it like this:

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GetDBConnection());
```

You may want to assign the `GetDBConnection()` to a var and check if it's empty before constructing your connection, it may be empty.

Comment: Thanks for your great code. i changed my code now as above (in my main question). now it opens on other computer but when i want to press insert button, to insert a data on my database, it shows me an error that it can not insert it in database. Could you pls help me to solve this last problem?
Thanksss.

Comment: @arash6657 if it answered your issue please mark the answer as accepted to let others know my solution helped that may have the same issue. If you have a different issue, create a new question.

Comment: Dear Çöđěxěŕ, i marked it green as answer but as it is the continue of the main problem which is still exist for me, could you please help me in this question?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not the issue you reported, you need to create another question with your *new issues* that doesn't relate to this. Create a new question with all relevant code, steps to reproduce your issue and what you've tried so everyone can help out.